# CFContent tag in CFSavecontent prompts user to download .cfm file

Tags: coldfusion

I wrote a ColdFusion file that grabs some data from a database and stores it in an array and populates some variables. I then format this in an html table and output it to an excel file that is saved on the server.

The issue I'm having is when the page is accessed, the file gets written, but the browser is also prompted to download the cfm file. For example I visit the page (`bla/bla/get_open_today.cfm`) the file is written, but the brower also wants to download `get_open_today.cfm`. Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Here is the code for the output to excel:

```
<!--- Export to XLS file --->
<cfsavecontent variable="saveContent1">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel">
<cfoutput>
<table border="1">
</tr>
<th >Hall ID</th>
<th >Room Number</th>
<th >Room Type</th>
<th >In Date</th>
<th >Clean Date</th>
<th >Comments</th>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(myarray)#">
    <tr><td>#myarray[x][1]#</td><td> #myarray[x][2]# </td><td>#myarray[x][3]# </td><td>#myarray[x][4]#                                  </td><td>#myarray[x][5]#</td><td>#myarray[x][6]#</td></tr>
</td>
</cfloop>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>One Bedroom</td>
        <td>#oneBR#</td>
        <td>Units Assigned</td>
        <td>#unitsAssigned#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two Bedroom</td>
        <td>#twoBR#</td>
        <td>Units Unassigned</td>
        <td>#unitsUnassigned#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three Bedroom</td>
        <td>#threeBR#</td>
        <td>Total Units</td>
        <td>#totalUnits#</td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>

</table>
</cfsavecontent>
<cffile action="write" mode="777" output="#saveContent1#" file="Example/www/BFILES/Unit_Report.xls">
```

Answer (score 4):

**Remove the [cfcontent](http://cfdocs.org/cfcontent)** - this is setting the content type header of the page to an unhandled type, and thus prompting the browser to provide a download.

The purpose of cfcontent is to send information to the client - using inside cfsavecontent has no effect, because savecontent is just a convenient way of doing cfset on large strings.

You cannot use / do not need cfcontent to save HTML as an XLS file.

Comment: Alvar, when a question is solved you should select the green tick next to the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

The technique of using html table tags for excel exports became a bad way of doing things when MS released Office 2007.  It still works, but not very well.

Fortunately there are better ways.  Later versions of ColdFusion have a cfspreadsheet tag.  If your version is not sufficiently recent, Ben Nadel's blog has a link to the Apache POI which you can use.